# Pigeon hole exercise

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

I have an exercise that it is pigeon hole principle.I have to ask you if i solve it right.
The question is :
There is a university, the students get in the univeristy ) from  the 2003 year until 2018.How many at least students ,must come in a party that  university does,if there must be for sure at least 10 students(the same year) ?
What i did is i count years from 2003 until 2018 and it is 15 years so i did the pigeon hole principle i got the 15 years  : 10 at least students ,that i did `[15/10]=[1.5] =2`

Comment: I'm sorry but the current wording of this question makes it impossible to understand. *And sentences start with capital letters*.

Comment: i will try again

Comment: @klangen did you get better the meaning now?

Comment: You changed nothing.

Comment: Is the question: How many people from the university do you need to have at a party to be sure that there are at least ten people who are in the same year at the university? An do you honestly expect the answer to be 2 people? Think about the maximum number of people there could be at the party WITHOUT there being 10 from the same year. Then add one more person.

Comment: i know its wrong , but i didn't thought something else ...that'w why i wrote it here to tell me what should have i done

Comment: @JaapScherphuis i didn't get what you mean.How can i calculate the full number of students if i haven't them?

Comment: Suppose you have a party and there are NOT 10 people from the same year. At most how many people can there be at the party from 2003? At most how many can there be at the party from 2004? etc.

Comment: I don't know  cause the exercise don't reffer.You gave me an idea you mean that in 2003 i will have 10 ,in 2004 i will have 10,in 2005 i will have 10  and i will add every 10 from each year and i will have the least number of all years,if there are comming 10 people from same year? so 15 years   * 10 at least = 150 at least person will come from all years together?

Comment: I said a party WITHOUT 10 poeple of each year. *without*.

Comment: i have no idea cause the number  doesn't be writtent in the exercise.It just say that get in students from 2003 until 2018.It doesn't say the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you are at the door of the party and choosing who to let in. You are trying to avoid letting in $10$ people from the same year at university. You can then let in nine people from 2003, but not a tenth. Similarly, you can let in nine people from 2004, but not a tenth. The same goes for all the other years too, so you can let in $9$ people from each of the years 2003 to 2018. That is $9\times16=144$ people, because there are $16$ years (2003 and 2018 are both included).

If you now let a $145$th person in, they must be from one of the years 2003 to 2018, and therefore must complete a group of ten from the same year. So it seems $145$ is the smallest party for which you are sure to have $10$ people from the same year.

You can prove it with the (generalized) pigeonhole principle as follows:
If you split $145$ university people into their $16$ year groups, the average group size is $145/16 = 9+\frac{1}{16}$. Therefore there must be at least one group with more than $9$ people (i.e. $10$ or more).

Comment: its clear to me now ,thank you a lot man :)